# Are all of the islands in Myst on the same planet?

Tags: video-games, myst

In the game Myst, one can travel from island to island with some magic books. If the sailing vessel on the main island were operational, could one take it to visit the other islands? Are all of the Myst islands located on the same planet?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here's a quote from [The Book of D'ni](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Myst_Reader):

> Atrus looked up at the night sky, wondering, not for the first time, just when he was. From his studies of the star charts in the observatory, he had worked out that he was in a very different part of the galaxy from the planet he knew as Earth—or its equivalent—if one even existed in this Age. But it was more difficult to tell just how far he was from it in time, for when one linked there were no limits. The mind-staggering vastnesses of Time and Space were irrelevant. Congruity —the matching of word and place—was all that mattered.
>
> Or, as his grandfather, Aitrus, had explained it to his grandmother, Anna: “These Ages are worlds that do exist, or have existed, or shall. Providing the description fits, there is no limitation of time and space. The link is made regardless.”

The implication from the quote is that Atrus believes that the books link to a different world in the same galaxy but not necessarily a contemporaneous one.  Later on in the novel an old linking book is found and through experiments the characters deduce that it links to [a world](http://dni.wikia.com/wiki/Sedona) whose star has gone supernova and destroyed the world.

Comment: There's also a quote in the Book of Ti'ana that's relevant, where a certain character explains to a young Ghen that you can never link within an age, only from one age to another.

Answer (score 10):

Each age is a separate and distinct universe.

In [*The Book of Atrus*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Myst_Reader#Book_of_Atrus) Gehn shows Atrus how to make ages and how to travel from one to the other.  It's possible to make an age that doesn't support life, which would mean that age is not in the same universe, with the same physical laws, as all the others.  He is quite clear to Atrus that if you go into an age and do not carry a linking book with you, *there is no way to leave it*.

Once you go into an age, you're in a self contained universe.  You can't make a boat or build a bridge or swim to another age.  Without a linking book, you're lost in that age for the rest of your life or until someone comes through with a linking book.

Comment: If you include Myst V or Uru as canon, then you should add an exception as the Bahro can link at will (as can Yeesha - but Yeesha opens a who new can of worms).

Comment: Another exception: the Star Fissure.  Though it is extremely unclear if that was a unique feature to the age of Riven (a byproduct of Gehn's sloppy writing?) or if such things could happen on any age.

Comment: I can't be sure, but my impression was the Star Fissure was essentially the void between ages.

Comment: Perhaps it is, but it's awfully convenient that the fissure just happens to lead to earth, and to a very specific place on earth.

Comment: Actually, the fissure isn't supposed to "lead" anywhere.  At the end of Riven, it's made clear that when you fall into it, you're drifting, with no actual destination.  I was always a bit disappointed that it was never made clear how the game player is rescued from there to be able to meet Atrus in _Exile_.

Comment: While they don't mention it in Exile / Revelations, we learn in Uru that everything that fell into the fissure landed in New Mexico. ;p

Comment: @Brandorf Why is it convenient? I guess it's convenient for the stranger to be able to go back home, but the only reason the stranger got the Myst book in the first place is that it fell through that same fissure to New Mexico.

Comment: @Brandorf Maybe it's not convenient, it merely happens that Earth was populated by those who fell through the fissure...